# The image set name "xxx" is used by multiple image sets with localized Asset Catalog (.xcassets)

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to use one Images.xcassets directory for each language supported by my app.

So in the finder I put one Images.xcassets directory in each .lproj directory

[image]

[image]

In xCode I have:

[image]

For both the english and french xcassets they have english and french checked in localization field in xCode.

[image]

But when I compile I've got warnings for all my images in the Asset Catalogs:

> The image set name "xxx" is used by multiple image sets

How can I correct the error ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't have two images with the same name on xcassets.

I found this because i had one image with this name 'default.png' for iPad and other with the same name for iPhone inside of a file of xcassets. The reason for your warning is because of this. Two images with the same name.

The solution is to have one image 'default.png' and inside configure the different devices that the image supports.

Comment: Yes I understand why I've got this error. But this is really annoying because xcasset should be localizable. Is there a way to localize xcassets properly ?

Comment: You have to create different targets. When you create a xcasset file you have to link this file to the specific target.

Check this link: [link](http://www.codeghost.co.uk/post/50912394435/multiple-ios-targets-from-a-single-xcode-project)

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something similar in wanting to swap out my app icons from different asset catalogs depending on whether I built debug, ad-hoc, or release. My solution was to not include the debug and ad-hoc catalogs in any targets, then write a run script in Swift to copy over those assets at runtime. Here's the script:

```
import Foundation

struct CopyNonReleaseIcons: Script {

    var usage: String {
        return "When running a non-release (Debug or AdHoc) build, switches out the app icon to help" +
            "differentiate between builds on the home screen.\n\n" +
            "Usage: swift CopyNonReleaseIcons.swift <CONFIGURATION> <PRODUCT_NAME> <BUILD_PATH>"
    }

    var expectedNumberOfArguments = 3

    func run(arguments arguments: [String]) {
        let configuration = arguments[0]
        let productName = arguments[1]
        let buildPath = arguments[2]

        if configuration == "Debug" || configuration == "AdHoc" {
            copyIcons(buildName: configuration, productName: productName, buildPath: buildPath)
        }
    }

    func copyIcons(buildName buildName: String, productName: String, buildPath: String) {
        let sourcePath = "My App/Resources/Asset Catalogs/" + productName + "SpecificAssets-" + buildName + "Icons.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/"

        var appName = "My App.app"
        if (productName == "White Label") {
            appName = "White Label.app"
        }

        shell(launchPath: "/bin/cp", arguments: ["-rf", sourcePath, buildPath + "/" + appName])
    }
}

CopyNonReleaseIcons().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to several sources online you can't localize images inside asset catalogs. Most of them reference Xcode 5.1.1, however as of Xcode 6.1 it appears you still can't localize them.  Its recommended to just remove the images from the asset catalogs and do it the old fashion way.

http://tang.io/wordpress/462

Comment: It's unbelievable. Apple provides a new way to manage assets in a project but doesn't permit to use localizaton on it. Why? What's the point?

Comment: When Apple finishes rewriting XCode in Swift they will probably add this feature.  Look for it in XCode 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, my solution is: an identifier for each cell set !
[image]